# How to get results from a background service but still keep it running in android

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm developing this dating app that allows users to browse profiles downloaded from a server.

But I'm not sure what kind of thread or service I should be using to do the uploading to and downloading from the server.

It has to be a service that runs in the background that first connects to the server via a socket and then waits for commands from user input (from the UI thread).

I read about the Service and IntentService classes.
IntentService seems to be appropriate except that it is destroyed once it has finished its job and returned a result to the calling thread. I need it to keep listening for requests.

I could start a new service each time but that means I would have to reconnect to the server with each request (let's say each time I browse a profile). That doesn't seem right.

Can anyone tell me what is the best approach for this purpose?

Comment: Trying to maintain a durable socket connection is challenging in mobile app development. Why are you going that route, rather than going with a Web service, using things like SPDY to keep socket connections around for a bit?

Comment: I didn't know using sockets was discouraged in mobile app development... I have already built this client-server communication code and wanted to transfer it to Android. I'm kind of new to network communication so I didn't know there were alternatives. So creating a web service is better than socket communication?

Comment: "I didn't know using sockets was discouraged in mobile app development" -- sockets are not discouraged. Durable socket connections are difficult to maintain in mobile devices, because those devices are mobile. Users walk around, get in elevators, drive, etc. This causes the mobile device to flip between different WiFi access points, fail over to mobile data, etc. Each time that sort of thing happens, existing socket connections have to be re-established. Hence, all else being equal, only use long-lived connections when you need such connections.

Comment: OK I understand. So in your opinion, would it be better to just connect to the server, download a bulk of profiles, save them in memory, close the connection and just browse the profiles from memory?

Comment: I do not know your app. I cannot say whether "download a bulk of profiles" is appropriate. All I am saying is that most mobile apps, like their Web app counterparts, do not rely upon long-lived socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to make the **client** send download/upload requests outside UI thread, then you could try using [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). I've been using that in almost every application I developed, and it is highly reliable.

But if you want to send data from **server** to the client (in other words, client keep listening for any incoming data), I recommend you to use [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Here is a step-by-step tutorial of [implementing GCM in Android device](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).